# Помогите решить задачку (Python)

Tags: python

Требуется написать программу, которая находит сумму и произведение цифр четырёхзначного числа x.
Формат входных данных
Входной поток содержит одно целое число x (1000≤x≤9999).
Формат выходных данных
Требуется в одной строке вывести два числа — сумму и произведение цифр числа x.

Comment: И что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: `input()` получаете число, с помощью `int` в число приводите, `print` выводите, сумму и произведение посчитать сможете

Comment: не получается полностью решить задачу ,сделал так x=int(input())
L=x % 1000 // 10  + 10
K=x % 1000  // 100 * 2
print(L,K) ответ не правильный частично

Comment: map(int, list(str(input_number))) - так получите список из цифр

Answer (score 2, accepted):

расписал чтоб было понятно, но на будущее, **прилагайте свои попытки, а то это выглядит будто вы просите решить что-либо за вас, а не просите помочь исправить ошибку**

```py
number = input()
digits, sum, multiply = [i for i in number], 0, 1
for digit in digits:
    sum += int(digit)
    multiply *= int(digit)

print(sum, multiply)
```

Comment: решение правильное ,но так мы еще не проходили))

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы называть переменную именем встроенной функции, лучше бы эту самую функцию использовать - sum(digits). Ну и перед этим [int(i) for i in number].

Comment: @Эникейщик еще можно так, раз уж на то пошло

from six.moves import reduce
number = list(map(int,input()))
print(sum(number), reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, number))

Comment: @Роман если подошло - пометь галочкой, если надо еще облегчить - скажи, люди тут не от скуки сидят)

Comment: @Роман если данный мною вам ответ вам угоден, отметьте его как верный и мы закроем тему, если же нет, сообщите каким бы вы хотели видеть решение

Comment: @Роман если вы решили свою задачу, приложите решение, если помогло мое - поставьте галочку

Comment: незачто, удачии в изучении языка!!)